# Error during Gnat Ada compiler installing

Tags: config, ada, gnat, gnat-gps

I'm trying to install GNAT Compiler for Ada programing, but when I launch it I get the following error: "Cannot create config directory C:/users/@#$%@#%#@/.gps/   Exiting...".

Somebody knows the solution?
I try all kind of things, nothing helped.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of things have you tried?
I installed the compiler in win7, and it works like a charm!

Comment: Which Windows? Which GNAT compiler bundle?

Comment: Can someone with a higher rep than me set up the tag `gps-gnat` (for example)? `gps` refers to the Global Positioning System - I tried to get "our" GPS added as an alternative meaning but failed.

Comment: [tag:gnat-gps] created.

Comment: What's the name of your Windows user? Does it have any special characters in it? It seems like your user name is substituted with `@#$%@#%#@` for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

I have Cygwin installed on Windows XP, with GPS from GNAT GPL 2012.

If I have `%HOME%` set to `C:\cygwin\users\%USERNAME%` and start GPS for the first time, GPS says that it created the configuration directory `C:\cygwin\users\simon\.gps`. If I don't set `%HOME%`, GPS creates the configuration directory `C:\Documents and Settings\Simon`, which appears to be `%HOMEPATH%`. Note that GPS isn't aware of Cygwin, it's a Windows application and uses your Windows environment variables.

I wonder whether you have `%HOME%` (or perhaps `%HOMEPATH%`?) set to a nonexistent directory? GPS doesn't seem to be able to create intermediate directories.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an Ada wiz but I remember that I tried to install Gnat GPS with Cygwin as well and had all sorts of problems. One of the biggest was the 64/32 bit incompatibility since Gnat on Windows is only available in the 32 bit version and Cygwin is probably in the 64 bit version on your machine

In the end my solution was to remove Cygwin completely and install Mingw32, which is the system Ada uses.